Analytics for blender addon?
I'm wondering if some Blender add-ons use Google Analytics or similar. I think this could bring valuable information, but I haven't found any mention of it on the internet.

That would go quite the opposite direction of Blender's philosophy of not tracking its users or gathering any data. And if there were any, I'm pretty sure it would be self hosted and not go through third party services or rely on any company other than the Blender Foundation.

Agree with the above. Technically or legally, I don't think there's anything preventing any addon dev to make use of such service, but ethically and practically it's unlikely to happen or be appreciated by the users.
